# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS : How can I modify KDE desktop launchers and use my environment variable

Tags: kde, launcher, environment-variables, ubuntu-studio

Bonjour, I'm relatively new to linux and have some problems.

A) Cannot modify KDE Plasma launchers.

Though I can launch from a terminal session, the modifications I write to the launchers through their "properties" are not saved.
I'm a member of groups sudo and adm
I've tried modifying the permissions (chmod ... ) without success.

```
user@user-kubuntu-pc:~/Desktop$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 39 Aug 24 15:17 jamulus.desktop -> /usr/share/applications/jamulus.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 46 Aug 24 15:17 jamulus-server.desktop -> /usr/share/applications/jamulus-server.desktop
user@user-kubuntu-pc:/usr/share/applications$ ls -l
(...)
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   649 Jul 29 11:56 jamulus.desktop
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   783 Aug 25 22:10 jamulus-server.desktop
(...)
```

How can I permanently modify launchers ?

B) Cannot use my environment variables with KDE.

In the launchers and the terminal, the path to my hard disk files is rather long and I'd like to use an environment variable to shorten it.
I set `$J_DAT="/media/user/Disque Dur/Media/My Music Tech and Other/Jamulus"` and `export` it,  but KDE seems to ignore it.

How do I tell KDE to use my environment variables ?

Context :
tower pc booting from Windows (SSD) or Ubuntu (SSD), sharing data on Windows NTFS hard disk.
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with KDE Plasma 5.24 LTS was recently installed for me.
I then installed Ubuntu Studio over it.
I then installed jamulus (online internet jamming, audio).
Jamulus client and server may be launched with parameters;
client ex.: `jamulus -i "/media/user/Disque Dur/Media/My Music Tech and Other/Jamulus/JamulusL.ini"` ).
Jamulus installed 2 desktop launchers for it's client and server.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please one focused question at a time on this site. Please delete the second question and feel free to ask it in a separate question.

Comment: After much searching and testing I found valid solutions :Answer to A)

Comment: *Bienvenue*, if you find the answer you should post it yourself to help out others who may have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding linux is a great exercise for my patience :-/
After much searching and testing I found these valid solutions :

Answer to A) For some reason I cannot save the modification made to the 'application>command' entry of the jamulus launcher properties (although i was able to save the modification to the jamulus-server launcher !?!).  However I have modified the /usr/share/applications/jamulus.desktop so the exec statement is : `Exec=jamulus -i "$J_DAT/JamulusL.ini"`. SOLVED

Answer to B) The following works to make an environment variable globally (KDE, bash, ...) , at least for 'user'.

- Created a bash script 'myprefs.sh' : `export J_DAT="/media/user/Disque Dur/Media/My Music Tech and Other/Jamulus"`
- `chmod ugo+x myprefs.sh`
- `mv myprefs.sh /etc/profile.d`
- rebooted
  SOLVED

Ref.:
[1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables
[2]: https://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables/en